# SpringBoot create record in MSSQL return null

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, mssql-jdbc

I am learning on SpringBoot performing CRUD on MSSQL, and I have encountered some issues, would like to get some advise. Thank you

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>app</name>
    <description>application1</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**User.java**

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private String role;
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
    
    public User(String name, String role) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.role = role;
    }
    
    public User() {
        super();
    }
}
```

**UserSQL.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserSQL extends User{
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      private long id;
      
      public UserSQL(String name, String role) {
          super(name, role);
          /*this.setName(name);
          this.setRole(role);*/
      }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

**MssqlRepository.java**

```
public interface MssqlRepository extends JpaRepository<UserSQL, Long> {
    
}
```

**UserController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    MssqlRepository ms;
    
    @PostMapping("/create")
    public Boolean createNewUser(@RequestBody User u){
        UserSQL userSQL = new UserSQL(u.getName(), u.getRole());    
        ms.save(userSQL);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I used Postman and pass in the name and role as RequestBody
[image]

then I query the MSSQL database, the name and role is NULL. Can someone advise where is the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove `extends User.`

The User you are using in your REST controller should not be extended by your DTO User.

The Entity should then look like below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserSQL {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      private long id;

      private String name; //create getter/setter
      private String role; //create getter/setter
      

}
```

Comment: The name and role attribute are inside the User.java

Comment: updated answer. @xxestter

Comment: Cannot do extend class?